# Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn - SignInUser() Launches safari

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, google-authentication

Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn 3.0.0
iPad 2 (Simulator) iOS 9.3

When I call

```
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser();
```

Safari is launched.

I have read that this is no longer permissible when submitting to the App Store.

Apparently there is a checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled() method in the Google SDK, but looking at the source code for it in https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents:

```
[Export ("checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled:")]
[Obsolete ("This method always calls back with |NO| on iOS 9 or above.", false)]
[EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[CompilerGenerated]
public unsafe virtual void CheckGoogleSignInAppInstalled ([BlockProxy (typeof (ObjCRuntime.Trampolines.NIDActionArity1V0))]global::System.Action<bool> callback)
```

The method is now obsolete.

What is the correct way to check for the google sign in application?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for Google rather than Xamarin.

It's probably not possible to use the Sign in app (Whatever that is) on ios simulators because they don't have the app store.

On a physical device I still get the browser popup, even with these options:

```
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.AllowsSignInWithWebView = false;
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.AllowsSignInWithBrowser = false;
```

Despite the fact that I have several google apps installed.

Further investigation required, but the question is basically invalid.